# join wireframe smooth surface

Tags: wireframe

Im trying to join two elements. Black with smooth surface and second with wireframe. The problem is that:

- first join option Im loosing wireframe effect
- second join option Im adding wireframe effect on black surface

I want join two element and have wireframe effect and smooth surface. How to do this?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the modifier first, then join the two objects.
The problem here might be, that when joining the objects the modifier gets overwriten by the object that was selected last.

Alternative: For differenciating between certain Edges/ Faces in the same Object you can use Vertex Groups in the Modifier.